# Flex binding in AS3 - Negate boolean value

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding, checkbox, boolean

I am binding a checkbox to a property on a control.  Everything is fine, but I need to bind the checkbox to another property, and the value needs to be the opposite of chkbox.checked.

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(obj, "propertyBool", checkBox, "selected");
```

I need something like this...

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(obj, "propertyBool", checkBox, "!selected");
```

but I'm not sure how to go about doing it in AS3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use BindingUtils's bindSetter method.  It works pretty much the same as the bindProperty method, but it fires a method which takes the value of the property you're binding to as an argument.

Something like the following:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(propertyBoolListener, checkBox, "selected");

private function propertyBoolListener(value:Boolean):void
{
    obj.propertyBool = !value;
}
```